# How to implement sort class

Tags: java

```
private class FileType extends Object {
    private String Name;
    private String Type;

    public FileType() {
        Name = null;
        Type = null;
    }

    public void setFileType(String n, String t) {
        Name = n;
        Type = t;
    }   

    public int compareTo(FileType ft) {
        String decodedFileName = null;
        String decodedInputName = null;
        try {
            decodedFileName = URLDecoder.decode(this.Name, "UTF-8");
            decodedInputName = URLDecoder.decode(ft.Name, "UTF-8");
        }
        catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        }
        return decodedFileName.compareToIgnoreCase(decodedInputName);
    }
}
```

Above code is my define class for file list.
I had implement compare file name.
The type may `Folder` or `File`.
But I want to sort file first priority is Type, and second priority is Name.
How can arrive it?

Comment: The `extends Object` is redundant and prevents legitimate inheritence.

Comment: I think you should implement comparable interface. And why extending object is implicitly required?

Comment: Your `compareTo` implementation uses neither name nor type.  I'm confused when I read your code.  And you don't follow the Sun coding standards, which is a bad sign to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (this.Type.equals(ft.Type)){
  return decodedFileName.compareTo(decodedInputName);
}
else{
  return this.Type.compareTo(ft.Type);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to implement Comparable / compareTo method.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Comparator` Interface from `java.util package` to **sort in more than one way......**

Use the `compare(T t1, T t2)` method of Comparator 
**Eg:**

**Here is an example from site** http://www.mkyong.com

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Fruit{

    private String fruitName;
    private String fruitDesc;
    private int quantity;

    public Fruit(String fruitName, String fruitDesc, int quantity) {
        super();
        this.fruitName = fruitName;
        this.fruitDesc = fruitDesc;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public String getFruitName() {
        return fruitName;
    }
    public void setFruitName(String fruitName) {
        this.fruitName = fruitName;
    }
    public String getFruitDesc() {
        return fruitDesc;
    }
    public void setFruitDesc(String fruitDesc) {
        this.fruitDesc = fruitDesc;
    }
    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }



    public static Comparator<Fruit> FruitNameComparator 
                          = new Comparator<Fruit>() {

        public int compare(Fruit fruit1, Fruit fruit2) {

          String fruitName1 = fruit1.getFruitName().toUpperCase();
          String fruitName2 = fruit2.getFruitName().toUpperCase();

          //ascending order
          return fruitName1.compareTo(fruitName2);

          //descending order
          //return fruitName2.compareTo(fruitName1);
        }

    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Compare both types. If the comparison is different from 0, return it as a result. If equal to 0, then compare the names.

Note that:

- Extending Object is unnecessary: it's the default
- Fields should start with a lower-case letter: name, type na dnot Name, Type
- Your class should implement `Comparable<FileType>`
- I would choose another name for the class: It's not a file type, but a file name associated to a file type
- I would use an enum rather than a String for file types, since you only have two valid instances of file types
- You should never ignore exceptions like you're doing. BTW, if this exception occurs, it could lead to a NullPointerException. Wrap the exception into a runtime exception and throw this runtime exception:

  ```
  catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
  ```
- Your compareTo method doesn't handle null names, although the default constructor assigns null to the name. Fix the method or the constructor. It seems to me that a file name should never be null, so I would fix the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You first compare the type and then the decoded name.
I cached the decodedFileName value directly in the class to prevent calling URLDecoder.decode too much.

```
private class FileType extends Object implements Comparable<FileType>{
    private String name;
    private String decodedFileName;
    private String type;
    public FileType(String n, String t) {
        name = n;
        try {
            decodedFileName = URLDecoder.decode(this.name, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }           
        type = t;
    }
    public int compareTo(FileType other) {
        int result = type.compareToIgnoreCase(other.type);
        if (result == 0){
            result = decodedFileName.compareToIgnoreCase(other.decodedFileName);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have only two types, why dont make them enum?
then first you compare type.ordinal, if there are equal then compare names,
and also prevents from putting unwanted values there